# htaccess 301 redirect example.com/beta/xyz to example.com/xyz

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need a general rule that maps every URL in the **`/beta`** subdirectory to the corresponding URL in the root; essentially I need to remove **`/beta`** from all URLs.

In case it makes any difference, the URLs are dynamically generated by WordPress.

Currently my **`.htaccess`** file is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>
#END WordPress
```

Can you tell me where to put the new lines?

Thank you!

Comment: for clarification, you want e.g. example.com/beta/abc to actually be the same as example.com/abc also do you want it so the browser redirects or still have the beta part showing in the address bar of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^beta/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear, but I would bet that what you want is having a Wordpress installed in `somedir/beta` appear in *yoursite.com/* instead of *yoursite.com/beta/*.  The rules you pasted are in `somedir/beta/.htaccess`, and are the default Wordpress rules.  You must leave those alone.

What you need for that is to put the following rules in the root directory, as in, `somedir/.htaccess`, after changing *example.com* to your own domain.  Your webserver first reads this root `.htaccess`, and when it does, it will know to rewrite requests to /beta.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/beta/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /beta/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ beta/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

More info in the Codex:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory